# Create custom controller and view in Umbraco CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, controller, umbraco

I have Installed the Umbraco CMS using NutGet package. I need to add my controller and views so that they can be integrated within Umbraco CMS.

Comment: I've made a blog post about using MVC forms in Umbraco, it might help a bit: [http://lukealderton.co.uk/blog/blog/2012/december/mvc-forms-in-umbraco/](http://lukealderton.co.uk/blog/blog/2012/december/mvc-forms-in-umbraco/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to implement something called [Surface Controllers](http://web-matters.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/umbraco-5-surface-controller.html). On a side note, be aware that the latest version of Umbraco (v5) is no longer supported. See Umbraco's [press release](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Umbraco 4.10 and upwards supports MVC